# Using TStringList.AddObject in Delphi Android FMX

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have a FMX TCombobox in my Delphi 10.3.3 app that I'm compiling for Android. I had previously researched the subject and found [Using Primitive Types with TStrings in iOS](http://blogs.riversoftavg.com/index.php/2013/08/01/using-primitive-types-with-tstrings-in-ios/). I downloaded `BoxPrimitives.pas` and the code below, compiled sucessfully under Delphi 10.3.3.

```
uses BoxPrimitives;

{$ifdef ANDROID}
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Male', TBoxInteger(1));
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Female', TBoxInteger(0));
{$else}
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Male', TObject(1));
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Female', TObject(0));
{$endif}
```

Now I've opened that source code in Delphi 10.4.1, and the `BoxPrimitives.Pas` no longer compiles.

> [DCC Error] BoxPrimitives.pas(46): E2123 PROCEDURE, FUNCTION,
> PROPERTY, or VAR expected

The general question then is: What changed in Delphi 10.4 that's preventing it from compiling? And more specifically: Is there a way to use `AddObject` with a `TCombobox` in `Android` in Delphi 10.4?

Comment: 10.4 no longer has ARC compiler, Windows code should work again on Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RAD Studio 10.4, Embarcadero decided to remove [ARC for object lifetime management](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers) on its mobile platforms.

[What's New in RAD Studio 10.4 Sydney](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/What%27s_New#Unified_Memory_Management)

> Unified Memory Management
>
> - Delphi memory management is now unified across all supported platforms - mobile, desktop, and server - **using the classic implementation of object memory management**. Compared to Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), this offers better compatibility with existing code and simpler coding for components, libraries, and end-user applications. The ARC model remains for string management and interface type references for all platforms.
> - For C++, this change means that the creation and deletion of Delphi-style classes in C++ follow normal memory management just like any heap-allocated C++ class, significantly reducing complexity.

The *correct* way to detect when ARC object lifetime management is being used, across all Delphi compiler versions and platforms, is to use [`{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers#ARC_and_the_.7B.24AUTOREFCOUNT.7D_Directive). This is even mentioned in the `BoxPrimitives.pas` unit:

> this class is only for use by AUTOREFCOUNT compilers

For example:

```pascal
{$ifdef AUTOREFCOUNT}
uses BoxPrimitives;
{$endif}

{$ifdef AUTOREFCOUNT}
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Male', TBoxInteger(1));
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Female', TBoxInteger(0));
{$else}
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Male', TObject(1));
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Female', TObject(0));
{$endif}

...

var Value: Integer;
{$ifdef AUTOREFCOUNT}
Value := TBoxInteger(cbGender.Items.Objects[index]);
{$else}
Value := Integer(cbGender.Items.Objects[index]);
{$endif}
```

---

That being said, I would probably take this a step further, by editing `BoxPrimitives.pas` to surround its code with `{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT} ... {$ELSE} ... {$ENDIF}`, and then in the `{ELSE}` section define `TBoxInteger` (and other types) as simple aliases, eg:

```pascal
interface

{$ifdef AUTOREFCOUNT}

uses
  Classes, Types, Generics.Defaults;

type
  TRSBoxPrimitive<T> = class(TObject)
    ...
  end;

  TBoxInteger = TRSBoxPrimitive<Integer>;
  TUnboxInteger = TBoxInteger;
  ...

{$else}

type
  TBoxInteger = TObject;
  TUnboxInteger = Integer;
  ...

{$endif}

implementation

{$ifdef AUTOREFCOUNT}

...

{$endif}

end.
```

Then you wouldn't need to `{$IFDEF}` your `AddObject()` calls at all, just use `TBoxInteger` and `TUnboxInteger` unconditionally on all platforms, eg:

```pascal
// look ma, no IFDEF's!
uses BoxPrimitives;

cbGender.Items.AddObject('Male', TBoxInteger(1));
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Female', TBoxInteger(0));
...
var Value: Integer;
Value := TUnboxInteger(cbGender.Items.Objects[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Dalija's comment, the answer then is to modify the code so it looks like this:

```
{$if defined(Android) and (CompilerVersion < 34)}
uses BoxPrimitives
{$endif}

{$if defined(Android) and (CompilerVersion < 34)}
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Male', TBoxInteger(1));
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Female', TBoxInteger(0));
{$else}
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Male', TObject(1));
cbGender.Items.AddObject('Female', TObject(0));
{$endif}
```